# How to loop into closest form inputs

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on the code below. Why am I not able to loop into the all inputs and get their data type?

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
   $(this).closest('form: input').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).data('type'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input data-type="text" type="text" name="fname">
 <input data-type="password" type="password" name="psw">
</form>

<button class="btn btn-secondary">Get Input Types</button>

<form>
 <input data-type="email" type="email" name="email">
 <input data-type="date" type="date" name="date">
</form>

<button class="btn btn-secondary">Get Input Types</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find parent elements with `closest`. As your button is not inside of `form` but it is next to it. So you can use `prev` selector and then use `find` to get `input` elements.

Also you can check answer by @Shubham Baranwal. Moving `button` inside `form` will also work.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).prev('form').find('input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('type'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input data-type="text" type="text" name="fname">
  <input data-type="password" type="password" name="psw">
</form>
<button class="btn btn-secondary">Get Input Types</button>


<form>
  <input data-type="email" type="email" name="email">
  <input data-type="date" type="date" name="date">
</form>

<button class="btn btn-secondary">Get Input Types</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put `buttons` inside of `form` tag and use below code to get your result. `closest` just work if you want to find parent element. So modify you code like below -

```js
$("button").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('form').find('input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('type'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input data-type="text" type="text" name="fname">
  <input data-type="password" type="password" name="psw">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary">Get Input Types</button>
</form>



<form>
  <input data-type="email" type="email" name="email">
  <input data-type="date" type="date" name="date">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary">Get Input Types</button>
</form>
```